# Draw at the center of a triangle (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a label at the center of a triangle without drawing the triangle itself?

I don't want the drawing of the triangle to interfere with other drawing elements, so I only want the label.

Comment: Depends on what you call the *center* of a triangle. If it's the isobarycenter, so Ignasi's answer is the best (and the shorter). If you want to display other centers, you should use `tikz-euclide` library which allows you to find all kind of centers in a triangle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=A] (A) circle (2pt);
\draw (2,5) coordinate[label=B] (B) circle (2pt);
\draw (4,2) coordinate[label=C] (C) circle (2pt);
\node at (barycentric cs:A=1,B=1,C=1) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]